# Bootstrap вызов нескольких модальных окон вызывает - черный экран

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, bootstrap4, modal

При каждом нажатии на клавишу вызываю функцию в которой идет обращение к серверным Api. В начале функции вызывают модальное окно с картинкой - загрузкой, однако после нескольких нажатий экран становиться полностью черными за счет кучи добавленных modal-backdrop fade in. Хотя перед вызовом нового окна закрываю старое.
Html:

```
<body id="stylesbase" style="margin:0px; height: 100%! important;width: 100%;overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="tab-content" style="min-width:780px; position:relative; top:50px;">
        <div id="panel8" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div style="padding-top:10px" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-12 column">
                        <input class="form-control" id="inptSearchLogic" type="text" placeholder="Поиск">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="progress_load">
        <div style="position:relative; left:45%; top: 45%; width: 105px;">
            <img src="img/loading.gif" width="100px" height="80px"/>
            <p style="text-align:center;background-color:wheat; ">Идет загрузка</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Js:

```
$("#inptSearchLogic").on("keyup", function() {
    $('#progress_load').modal('hide');
    $('#progress_load').modal('show');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            searchConnect: $('#inptSearchLogic').val(),
        },
        url: "path.php",
        success:function(data){
            $('#progress_load').modal('hide');
        }
    })
})
```

В итоге после нескольких нажатий получается такая верстка

```
<body id="stylesbase" style="margin:0px; height: 100%! important;width: 100%;overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="tab-content" style="min-width:780px; position:relative; top:50px;">
        <div id="panel8" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div style="padding-top:10px" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-12 column">
                        <input class="form-control" id="inptSearchLogic" type="text" placeholder="Поиск">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="progress_load">
        <div style="position:relative; left:45%; top: 45%; width: 105px;">
            <img src="img/loading.gif" width="100px" height="80px"/>
            <p style="text-align:center;background-color:wheat; ">Идет загрузка</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: В ajax success попадаете?

Comment: Да, если нажать 1 клавишу и дождаться закрытия модального окна на success, то все нормально. Проблема начинается, если нажатий происходит много. Не смотря на то, что я даже в начале функции обработки нажатия - закрываю модальное окно.